# Oracle DB - strange sql injection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sql-injection

While pentesting a website (yes, legally), an sql injection popped up, but I can't see how to use it currently. The query string looks like this, and the insertion point is at the first _ after values:

```
query = 'SELECT  item.a 
           FROM favitem item 
          WHERE ( item.a =?) AND (item.b=? )', values = [123456789_, 987654321]
```

a simple

```
, 1] UNION SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%'; --
```

doesn't return any values, but states it was successfull. It is always successful when it includes '%', even on random strings, that are unlikely to match at all. It returns an error when the it states `LIKE 'Oracle'` (without `%`). Any suggestions why this is always successful with `%`?

Comment: Which programming language is that? How are the placeholders (`?`) used in the DB acces code? Is that a prepared statement in the background or is the code actually doing string replacement.

Comment: I would have supposed that this is regular sql from oracle and that the placeholders are replaced with the values provided afterwards.

Comment: That is not "regular SQL". It is part of some kind of programming language (the `query = ...` defines a variable in whatever language you are using - it is a **not** valid SQL statement). Parameter markers like `?` are usually used in "prepared statements" which are not subject to SQL injection.

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry. The language should be java.

Comment: Then it is almost certainly a PreparedStatement and thus not subject to SQL injection - at least not the way you showed us - although the actualy code that is *executing* the statement is missing, and that is the important part. Although String literals use double quotes `"` in Java, not single quotes `'` and the comma notation for the `values` part also seems a bit strange. Are you using any framework? e.g. Spring JDBC Template?

Answer (score 2):

To find an injection is one thing but to ask community to write you an exploit for it - is another.

So, if you have found it - just report. That's what pentests are for.

Comment: On thing is that it is always better to give clients some data alongside with a sqli, but that's not what I asked for, but I'm looking for an explanation _why_ the `%` is neccessary and why it does seem to react positively even if there is no such entry.